# Drawing square over CameraPreview (android)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-camera

So I am trying to draw square over live CameraPreview.

I followed camera instructions on developer.android and I got CameraPreview class set up.
I was wondering how could I draw a square on top of the live image.

Something what we can see in face detection on cameras. I wont use it for face detection but same idea.

I have CameraPreview object that i place in my camera activity. Now any suggestions on how to go about learning about this or if you know of any code sample for it.

That would be great. And I am looking to do this in API 10. Not 14 which supports it through sdk.

This is what my current camera app code is based on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Thanks

Comment: i think you need to crop

Comment: crop???? not really just want to essentially have a layer that draws on top of the preview... but if you know some code sample with cropping that could help too

Comment: if you really need then i will help but not achieve your goal then it will time wasting

Answer (score 0):

Put your `SurfaceView` (which you need for the camera preview) inside of a `FrameLayout`. Then, you can put that square image right on top of the camera preview.

Comment: well its square frame. so its not image but any code example for what you are suggesting or link/resource?